# Detecting when two iphones bump into each other and send handshake signal

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I would like to detect when two iphones bump into each other so as to send some information to each other. Is there such an API for this task? Using ibeacon we can detect when two phones are in proximity, but does that narrow it down to when two phones are millimeters or less next to each other?

Comment: This was a thing a few years back. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_(application)

Comment: @picciano yes I'm looking to make this exact functionality!

Comment: I believe it sent a timestamp and location of each phone to a backend server that matched up "close" bumps and sent a push notification to each device. You will likely need a server to handle this process.

Comment: You could use BTLE https://github.com/lauraskelton/simple-share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific API for this. Nor is there an API that can tell you how close two iPhones are.

What you'd have to do is send some sort of broadcast message at the point of doing the bump. And also, be in a state (beforehand) of listening for this message from another device.

When you detect a bump message you can determine if it happened at the same time as your own bump and decide that that must be the phone it bumped with. You could have some margin of error for this time threshold.

You could also determine that they are within the same area purely from the strength of the iBeacon signal (possibly). Although, is that necessary if the bump time stamp is used?

Answer (score 1):

If the users are expected to wake up their phones and launch your app before bumping then you have lots of options. You could use the accelerometer to detect the shock of a bump, then broadcast timestamped notices to a central server. You could use GPS location to either narrow down the search for hits or to confirm it.

If you want your app to recognize bumps even when the devices are locked then your only real option is iBeacons. You could create a beacon region using a UUID for all of your devices, and then use the major/minor ID to identify individual devices. You'd have each device broadcast it's ID and listen for all devices using your UUID.

When you get notified of one of your devices in-range, you'd ask for background time and start ranging those beacons, as well as listening to the accelerometer for bumps. If you detect a bump and a beacon in immediate range, you could use a central server to link them up, or even use BLE to open a connection. The bad news is that once you start background processing, you only have 3 minutes before your app goes back to sleep. Thus in a situation like a business meeting where several people running your app might be in range for an extended period before bumping their phones, you might miss the bump.